# Default permission for draw over other app - true

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support, android-overlay

In my app I need to make default permission for draw over other app as true, like in most of the Android app.

How to do this in my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

This permission allow to draw over app

Enable it by redirecting user to setting page

if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

Comment: But in default it sets false, I need to set it as true.

Comment: It manually asks the user to turn it ON. But in some apps like Messenger, Facebook,..the default setting is ON. Is there any way to turn in ON defaultly when the app is installed.